# NoSuchFileException in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a problem with my JenkinsFile. When I load groovy script from the same directory, I get this message:

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /u01/jenkins_slave/workspace/SPAC_SPAC_BUILD_POLIGON-1727/build/notificationManager.groovy

I tried changing the path to absolute path "path() + /build/notificationManager.groovy" or only file path like this "notificationManager.groovy" or this "build/notificationManager.groovy". But I have the same problem in all this cases

What I do in code:

```
def runner = load "build/notificationManager.groovy"
runner.notifyEmail("FAILURE", ${DEVELOPERS})
```

Groovy function

```
def notifyEmail(buildStatus, emailRecipients) {

    try {

        def icon = "✅"
        def statusSuccess = true
        def hasArtifacts = true

        if(buildStatus != "SUCCESSFUL") {
            icon = "❌"
            statusSuccess = false
            hasArtifacts = false
        }

        def body = emailTemplate([
            "jenkinsText"   :   env.JOB_NAME,
            "jenkinsUrl"    :   env.BUILD_URL,
            "statusSuccess" :   statusSuccess,
            "hasArtifacts"  :   hasArtifacts,
            "downloadUrl"   :   "www.downloadurl.com"
        ]);

        mail (to: emailRecipients.join(","),
            subject: "${icon} [ ${env.JOB_NAME} ] [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}] - ${buildStatus} ",
            body: body,
            mimeType: 'text/html'
        );

    } catch (e){
        println "ERROR SENDING EMAIL ${e}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are loading a groovy script into a pipeline, the groovy file must include 'return this' at the bottom.

```
def notifyEmail(buildStatus, emailRecipients) {
...
}

return this;
```

Jenkins documentation: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script